# Wordcloud from Data Table in R

Tags: r, data-visualization, sentiment-analysis

I have a data table made from positive and negative word associations. I would like to create two wordclouds, one for positive words and one for negative words.

Example of `sentiment_words` table:

```
          element_id    sentence_id   negative     positive
1115:          1        1115          limits       agree,available
1116:          1        1116          slow         strongly,agree
1117:          1        1117                       management
1118:          1        1118                                      
1119:          1        1119          concerns     strongly,agree,better,
```

I am using `library(wordcloud)` and `library(sentimentr)`

For example, how do I pull only the words from the "positive" column to create a wordcloud? I'm not sure how to address the fact that there are multiple words associated with each row (e.g., "agree, available" should be treated as two entries)

I've made different attempts at the `wordcloud()` function such as
`wordcloud(words = sentiment_words$positive, freq = 3, min.freq = 1, max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per=0.35, colors=brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))` but this only returns a cloud with the term in the first entry

Edit: I've tried the `tidyverse` answer below, and the result I get is:

   `words                      n
   <chr>                  <int>
 1 " \"ability\""             3
 2 " \"ability\")"            1
 3 " \"acceptable\")"         1
 4 " \"accomplish\""          1
 5 " \"accomplished\")"       1
 6 " \"accountability\""      1
 7 " \"accountability\")"     1
 8 " \"accountable\""         2
 9 " \"accountable\")"        1`

I've tried multiply variants of `gsub()` and `apply` to remove the extra `)` and `c(` but haven't found anything that works yet. The result is words that should be counted together are counted separately (e.g., "acceptable" and "acceptable)" are two different words in the wordcloud)

Edit: In order to get it to work correctly, I had to first clean up my `sentiment_words` as suggested below.

```
for (j in seq(sentiment_words)) {
  sentiment_words[[j]] <- gsub("character(0)", "", sentiment_words[[j]])
  sentiment_words[[j]] <- gsub('"', "", sentiment_words[[j]])
  sentiment_words[[j]] <- gsub("c\\(", "", sentiment_words[[j]])
  sentiment_words[[j]] <- gsub(" ", "", sentiment_words[[j]])
  sentiment_words[[j]] <- gsub("\\)", "", sentiment_words[[j]])  
}
```

and I had to also filter out the remaining "character(0" strings within the `count_words` function. Note that it filters "character(0" and not "character(0)" because I removed the closing parenthesis above

```
filter(!!var != "character(0") %>%
```

Implementing the above gave the cleanest wordcloud based on polarity of text

Comment: Could you please specify your question and may add an example what you tried so far? I am not sure, what your problem is.

Comment: The problem is that the columns the user is trying to extract are nested list columns, not atomic vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse`-based approach that should get you started. I agree with Mr_Z in that I'm not entirely clear on where the problem is.

1. Let's define a function that generates a `data.frame` with the word count based on comma-separated words in a specific column `var` of your source data `df`.

   ```
   library(tidyverse)
   count_words <- function(df, var) {
       var <- enquo(var)
       df %>%
           separate_rows(!!var, sep = ",") %>%
           filter(!!var != "") %>%
           group_by(!!var) %>%
           summarise(n = n()) %>%
           rename(words = !!var)
   }
   ```
2. We can then generate word counts for the `positive` and `negative` columns

   ```
   df.pos <- count_words(df, positive)
   df.neg <- count_words(df, negative)
   ```

   Let's inspect the `data.frame`s

   ```
   df.pos
   # A tibble: 5 x 2
     words          n
     <chr>      <int>
   1 agree          3
   2 available      1
   3 better         1
   4 management     1
   5 strongly       2

   df.neg
   # A tibble: 3 x 2
     words        n
     <chr>    <int>
   1 concerns     1
   2 limits       1
   3 slow         1
   ```
3. Let's plot the word clouds

   ```
   library(wordcloud)
   wordcloud(words = df.pos$words, freq = df.pos$n, min.freq = 1,
             max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35,
             colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
   ```

   [image]

   ```
   wordcloud(words = df.neg$words, freq = df.neg$n, min.freq = 1,
             max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35,
             colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"))
   ```

   [image]

Comment: Sorry, there was a reference error related to the first comment. Looking at your `count_words()` function, how can I clean up the terms for special characters (e.g., especially `c(` and `"`) and how can I remove entries that show up as `character(0)`? The `character(0)` shows up when there is no entry in a particular row for the positive/negative columns

Comment: @coolhand Based on the example data you give, the "empty" entries are already removed in the `filter(!!var != "")` step. Not sure what you mean by special characters. It should be fairly straightforward to add any additional data polishing steps in the `dplyr` chain in function `count_words`. It's difficult to give more specific help without representative sample data.

Comment: I was able to modify the function to remove the `character(0)` but the special characters still remain. For example, there are separate entries for `agree`, `c("agree`, and `"agree"` within the wordcloud

Comment: That seems to be an issue related to how you generate the `sentiment_words` table; I would recommend fixing this at the level of the actual word extraction.

Comment: I've checked the values of `sentiment_words` manually and the extraction doesn't seem to be the issue. Is it possibly a result of how `count_words` is parsing multiple strings from the same row?In the execution, I get a warning "argument is not an atomic vector; coercing"

Comment: I use `sentiment_words <- get_sentences(fileText) %>% extract_sentiment_terms()` to build the data

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly advise against using the accepted answer here as it ignores that **sentimentr** already returns the computed counts for you (via `attributes(sentiment_words)$counts`).  The [documentation for `extract_sentiment_terms` shows examples](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sentimentr/versions/2.6.1/topics/extract_sentiment_terms) that makes this more clear (there's was room for improving the documentation about what is returned and has been added in the dev version: https://github.com/trinker/sentimentr/blob/master/R/extract_sentiment_terms.R).  Below I show how to extract the counts for use in a wordcloud and some potential layouts:

```
library(sentimentr)
library(wordcloud)
library(data.table)

set.seed(10)
x <- get_sentences(sample(hu_liu_cannon_reviews[[2]], 1000, TRUE))
sentiment_words <- extract_sentiment_terms(x)

sentiment_counts <- attributes(sentiment_words)$counts
sentiment_counts[polarity > 0,]

par(mfrow = c(1, 3), mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
## Positive Words
with(
    sentiment_counts[polarity > 0,],
    wordcloud(words = words, freq = n, min.freq = 1,
          max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35,
          colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"), scale = c(4.5, .75)
    )
)
mtext("Positive Words", side = 3, padj = 5)

## Negative Words
with(
    sentiment_counts[polarity < 0,],
    wordcloud(words = words, freq = n, min.freq = 1,
          max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35,
          colors = brewer.pal(8, "Dark2"), scale = c(4.5, 1)
    )
)
mtext("Negative Words", side = 3, padj = 5)

sentiment_counts[, 
    color := ifelse(polarity > 0, 'red', 
        ifelse(polarity < 0, 'blue', 'gray70')
    )]

## Together
with(
    sentiment_counts[polarity != 0,],
    wordcloud(words = words, freq = n, min.freq = 1,
          max.words = 200, random.order = FALSE, rot.per = 0.35,
          colors = color, ordered.colors = TRUE, scale = c(5, .75)
    )
)
mtext("Positive (red) & Negative (blue) Words", side = 3, padj = 5)
```

[image]